# ¿Por qué si tengo dos parámetros de función con el mismo nombre, el último no sobrescribe el contenido del primero, como si ocurre con las variables?

Tags: php

```
<?php

function clasic_clean ( $p ) {

$p2 = "<ins> $p </ins>";
$p2 = "<b> $p </b>";
$p2 = "<mark> $p </mark>";

echo $p2;
}
clasic_clean( "hola" );

?>
```

El código de arriba imprime en pantalla la palabra "hola", UNICAMENTE con el estilo de la etiqueta MARK; es decir, tenemos la palabra "hola" con su fondo pintado de color amarillo. Porque la tercera variable sobrescribe los estilos de las dos primeras.

```
<?php

function clasic_clean ( $p ) {

$p = "<ins> $p </ins>";
$p = "<b> $p </b>";
$p = "<mark> $p </mark>";

echo $p;
}
clasic_clean( "hola" );
```

?>

Aquí en cambio, el problema se soluciona, porque está sucediendo lo que yo quería, que era que a un texto se le aplicaran tres estilos al mismo tiempo. POr lo tanto, el resultado es que la palabra "hola", tiene el fondo amarillo del MARK, mas el estilo de subrayado de la etiqueta INS, mas el estilo negrita de la etiqueta B. Y todo esto por establecer el parámetro de la función como nombre de la variable.

El problema lo tengo solucionado ya, pero no entiendo el porqué de las cosas. Y quisiera que alguien me hiciera el favor de explicarme por qué sí funciona en el segundo ejemplo; dado que a mí no me gusta hacer algo sin entenderlo. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay demasiado misterio. Veamos:

## Primer caso

```
function clasic_clean ( $p ) {
    $p2 = "<ins> $p </ins>";
    $p2 = "<b> $p </b>";
    $p2 = "<mark> $p </mark>";
    echo $p2;
}
clasic_clean( "hola" );
```

En la primera línea creas una nueva variable `$p2` y en las líneas subsiguientes reemplazas su valor sin más, usando de nuevo el parámetro `$p`, por lo tanto cada línea es como crear una variable con un valor nuevo.

Mira esto:

```
function clasic_clean ( $p ) {
    $p2 = "<ins> $p </ins>"; #Aquí se usa $p
    $p2 = "<b> $p2 </b>";    #Aquí se usa $p2
    $p2 = "<mark> $p2 </mark>";
    echo $p2;
}
clasic_clean( "hola" );
```

Ahí funciona como esperado, ¿por qué?, porque en la primera línea tomamos el valor del parámetro (`$p`), lo guardamos en `$p2` y en lo adelante seguimos modificando en base a eso (dado que a partir de la segunda línea usamos `$p2`).

En esa primera asignación `$p2` vale esto:

```
<ins> hola </ins>
```

y en las asignaciones sub-siguientes valdrá:

```
<b> $p2 </b>          #O sea <b> <ins> hola </ins> </b>
<mark> $p2 </mark>    #O sea <mark> <b> <ins> hola </ins> </b> </mark>
```

Haciendo eso, el comportamiento es similar al segundo caso.

## Segundo caso

```
function clasic_clean ( $p ) {
    $p = "<ins> $p </ins>";        #<ins> hola </ins>
    $p = "<b> $p </b>";            #El valor anterior de $p rodeado de <b> </b>   
    $p = "<mark> $p </mark>";      #El valor anterior de $p rodeado de <mark> </mark>
    echo $p;
}
clasic_clean( "hola" );
```

Nada que decir, todo empieza bien, porque en la primera línea ya pusimos el parámetro `$p` y todo lo demás ocurre como ya se explicó más arriba.